# How can I make my code more pythonic? Iterating through a list isn't acceptable?

Tags: python

I've been told that iterating over a list as such is not appropriately pythonic. How do I make this part...

```
for i in range(0, len(word)):
            if words[i] == guess:
                guessable_list[i] = guess
                letters_to_guess -= 1
```

more pythonic.

**Background**

I'm working on a problem (the last problem called hangman) assigned MIT OC. I am working on this stuff by myself. So far the material is accessible and well taught. However, since I don't have a supervisor coupled with the awareness of how bad habits can develop when doing I would really appreciate it if anyone could look at my code and see if I'm doing anything wrong - from the use of idioms or my structuring of my code. Any feedback is appreciated.
Thank you all!

I have tried doing this...

```
for letter in words:
        if letter == guess:
            guessable_list[word.index(letter)] = guess
            letters_to_guess -= 1
```

but I encountered trouble where if a letter appears twice in a word it isn't replaced.

Comment: Perhaps you could reduce this code to a [mcve]. The whole lot can't all be relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) here:

```
for index, word in enumerate(words):
    if word == guess:
        guessable_list[index] = guess
        letters_to_guess -= 1
```

Comment: @jmecs No problem. Feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer then. ;-)